# expanding rows out by two year columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to expand out my data by `begyrs` and `endyrs`. The data I have looks like:

```
   pdpcols pdpvalues begyrs begyrsvalues gvkeys gvkeysvalues endyrs endyrsvalues
   <chr>       <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>         <int>
 1 pdpco1     138490 begyr1         1998 gvkey1       138490 endyr1         2001
 2 pdpco1     138490 begyr1         1998 gvkey1       138490 endyr2         2005
 3 pdpco1     138490 begyr2         2003 gvkey1       138490 endyr1         2001
 4 pdpco1     138490 begyr2         2003 gvkey1       138490 endyr2         2005
 5 pdpco2       6266 begyr1         1998 gvkey1       138490 endyr1         2001
 6 pdpco2       6266 begyr1         1998 gvkey1       138490 endyr2         2005
 7 pdpco2       6266 begyr2         2003 gvkey1       138490 endyr1         2001
 8 pdpco2       6266 begyr2         2003 gvkey1       138490 endyr2         2005
 9 pdpco1     138490 begyr1         1998 gvkey1       138490 endyr1         2001
10 pdpco1     138490 begyr1         1998 gvkey1       138490 endyr2         2005
```

What I would like to do is expand the data such that, the rows will be expanded from the `begyrsvalues` to the `endyrsvalues` for each observation. So row 1 would be expanded from `1998` to `2001` and row 2 expanded from `1998` to `2005`. This would generate quite a number of duplicate values.

I have tried `group_by(gvkeysvalues)` and then tried to expand them without luck.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(source = c("MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", 
"MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", 
"MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "m2006", "m2006", 
"m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "MTCH1", 
"MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", "MTCH1", 
"m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", 
"m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", "m2006", 
"m2006", "m2006", "PASS1", "PASS1", "PASS1", "PASS1", "PASS1", 
"PASS1", "PASS1", "PASS1", "PASS1"), id = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 3786L, 3786L, 3786L, 3786L, 3786L, 3786L, 3786L, 3786L, 
5432L), cod = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("01 Unassigned", "02 US corporation", "03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned", 
"04 US individual", "05 Foreign individual", "06 US government", 
"07 Foreign government", "08 US local government", "09 US state government", 
"US university", "Foreign university", "US institute", "Foreign institute", 
"US hospital/med inst", "Foreign hospital/med inst"), class = "factor"), 
    cod_fix = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), pdpass = c(12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 
    12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 
    12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 
    11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 
    11864228L, 11864228L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 
    12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 12233315L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 
    11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 
    11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 11864228L, 
    11864228L, 11864228L, 11146104L, 11146104L, 11146104L, 11146104L, 
    11146104L, 11146104L, 11146104L, 11146104L, 11628725L), standard_name = c("3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", 
    "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", 
    "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", 
    "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", 
    "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", 
    "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", "3 DIMENSIONAL PHARM INC", 
    "3D LABS INC LTD", "3D LABS INC LTD", "3D LABS INC LTD", 
    "3D LABS INC LTD", "3D LABS INC LTD", "3D LABS INC LTD", 
    "3D LABS INC LTD", "3D LABS INC LTD", "3D PHARM INC", "3D PHARM INC", 
    "3D PHARM INC", "3D PHARM INC", "3D PHARM INC", "3D PHARM INC", 
    "3D PHARM INC", "3D PHARM INC", "3DLABS INC LED", "3DLABS INC LED", 
    "3DLABS INC LED", "3DLABS INC LED", "3DLABS INC LED", "3DLABS INC LED", 
    "3DLABS INC LED", "3DLABS INC LED", "3DLABS INC LTD", "3DLABS INC LTD", 
    "3DLABS INC LTD", "3DLABS INC LTD", "3DLABS INC LTD", "3DLABS INC LTD", 
    "3DLABS INC LTD", "3DLABS INC LTD", "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", 
    "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", 
    "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", 
    "CAMBRIDGE SOUNDWORKS INC", "CREATIVE TECH LTD"), uspto_assignee = c(715707L, 
    715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 
    715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 
    715707L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 
    727325L, 727325L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 
    715707L, 715707L, 715707L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 
    727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 
    727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 727325L, 85595L, 85595L, 
    85595L, 85595L, 85595L, 85595L, 85595L, 85595L, 721579L), 
    pdpcols = c("pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco2", 
    "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", 
    "pdpco1", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco1", 
    "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", 
    "pdpco2", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco2", 
    "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", 
    "pdpco1", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco1", 
    "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", 
    "pdpco2", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco1", "pdpco2", 
    "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco2", "pdpco1"), pdpvalues = c(138490L, 
    138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 6266L, 6266L, 6266L, 6266L, 138490L, 
    138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 6266L, 6266L, 6266L, 6266L, 64005L, 
    64005L, 64005L, 64005L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 138490L, 
    138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 6266L, 6266L, 6266L, 6266L, 64005L, 
    64005L, 64005L, 64005L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 64005L, 
    64005L, 64005L, 64005L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 30060L, 
    30060L, 30060L, 30060L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L
    ), begyrs = c("begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", 
    "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", 
    "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", 
    "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", 
    "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", 
    "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", 
    "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", 
    "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", 
    "begyr2", "begyr1", "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1", 
    "begyr1", "begyr2", "begyr2", "begyr1"), begyrsvalues = c(1998L, 
    1998L, 2003L, 2003L, 1998L, 1998L, 2003L, 2003L, 1998L, 1998L, 
    2003L, 2003L, 1998L, 1998L, 2003L, 2003L, 1995L, 1995L, 2002L, 
    2002L, 1995L, 1995L, 2002L, 2002L, 1998L, 1998L, 2003L, 2003L, 
    1998L, 1998L, 2003L, 2003L, 1995L, 1995L, 2002L, 2002L, 1995L, 
    1995L, 2002L, 2002L, 1995L, 1995L, 2002L, 2002L, 1995L, 1995L, 
    2002L, 2002L, 1993L, 1993L, 1998L, 1998L, 1993L, 1993L, 1998L, 
    1998L, 1992L), gvkeys = c("gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", 
    "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", 
    "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", 
    "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", 
    "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", 
    "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey1", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", 
    "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", 
    "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", 
    "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", 
    "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey1"), gvkeysvalues = c(138490L, 
    138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 
    138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 
    138490L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 
    25773L, 25773L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 
    138490L, 138490L, 138490L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 
    25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 
    25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 
    25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L, 25773L), endyrs = c("endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", "endyr2", "endyr1", 
    "endyr2", "endyr1"), endyrsvalues = c(2001L, 2005L, 2001L, 
    2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 
    2001L, 2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 
    2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 2001L, 2005L, 
    2001L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 
    2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 
    1997L, 2005L, 1997L, 2005L, 1997L, 2005L, 1997L, 2005L, 2006L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe you are looking for this solution

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  select(pdpcols, begyrsvalues, endyrsvalues) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(out = list(seq(begyrsvalues, endyrsvalues))) %>% 
  unnest(out)
```

The `select` line can be removed. I left her for an example

Answer (score 3):

We can subtract the two values (diffs) and replicate each row with `diffs` number of times. We can do that using `slice`. Note that there were negative values (i.e. endyrs < begyrs) which we replace with 1 so the sequence is valid, i.e.

```
data %>% 
 mutate(diffs = endyrsvalues - begyrsvalues, 
        diffs = replace(diffs, diffs < 0, 1)) %>% 
 slice(rep(seq(diffs), diffs)) %>% 
 select(-diffs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Add id row
dat <- dat %>% rowid_to_column(var = "rowid") 

# Build table of years
years_tab <- dat %>% 
  select(rowid, begyrsvalues, endyrsvalues) %>% 
  transmute(rowid, year_seq = map2(begyrsvalues, endyrsvalues, seq)) %>% 
  unnest

# Join them
left_join(years_tab, dat, "rowid")
```